# Problems understanding authorization

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm having problems in understanding how to authorize my program to perform privileged tasks.

I read the apple documentation and wrote this piece of code:

```
AuthorizationRef myAuthorizationRef;
OSStatus myStatus = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &myAuthorizationRef);

AuthorizationItem myItem;

myItem.name = "com.Me.myApp.test";
myItem.valueLength = 0;
myItem.value = NULL;
myItem.flags = 0;

AuthorizationRights myRights;

myRights.count = 1;
myRights.items = &myItem;

AuthorizationFlags myFlags = kAuthorizationFlagDefaults |
kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed |
kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;

myStatus = AuthorizationCopyRights (myAuthorizationRef, &myRights, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, myFlags, NULL);
```

after calling AuthorizationCopyRights I should be able to perform privileged tasks, right? Is there still something I've got to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right you are requesting, com.Me.myApp.test, is not a privileged right, and so acquiring it does not give your application elevated permissions.  However, that is a good thing -- you don't want your cocoa app to have elevated privileges because of [Input Managers](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?InputManager).  This deprecated technology permits anyone to load arbitrary code into your application, so if you elevate the privileges of your app, it becomes an attack vector.

A more secure approach is to write a helper tool.  See Apple's [guide to secure coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html) and [using a helper tool](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/03authtasks/authtasks.html).